# Como modificar uma url enviada pelo formulário via get [Codeigniter]?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-amigável, route, url-rewrite

Pessoal eu preciso modificar uma url mas não sei como fazer isso. Eu tenho a url seguinte:

```
http://wedding.axitech.com.br/?procuraonde=Palhoça&procuraoque=bolos
```

e preciso transformar na url abaixo:

```
http://wedding.axitech.com.br/palhoca/bolos
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a chegar a este resultado no **Codeigniter**?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma rota onde os segmentos passarão a ser os parâmetros get para o método de um controlador ou informar na url o nome do controlador e o método desejado no primeiro e segundo segmento respectivamente da url. Segmento é cada valor passado entre as barras da url a contar a partir da url base do site. A sequência é: `url_base/controlador_ci/metodo_do_controlador/parametro1/paramentro2/`... Onde `controlador_ci` é o primeiro segmento, `metodo_do_controlador` o segundo segmento, e assim por diante. Segue exemplo de como seria a url que você deseja com rota.

url: `http://wedding.axitech.com.br/buscar/palhoca/bolos`

acesse o arquivo `application/config/routes.php` e crie a rota `$route['buscar'] = 'Busca/efetua_busca';`;

crie o seguinte controlador:

**Controller**

```
public class Busca extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function efetua_busca($onde, $oque) {
        /* $onde receberá palhoca e $oque receberá bolos. 
           A sequência é a mesma que passada na url */

        echo $onde; // imprime palhoca
        echo $oque; // imprime bolos
    }
}
```